# Is there a way to pick an audio file which I generate from OneNote with windows-phone 8.1?

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8.1, onenote

I am using wp silverlight 8.1 and windows phone 8.1,

I am wondering if I can pick an audio file that is generated with OneNote for instance with the FileOpenPicker API.

Or I can only pick and audio that is created by my own app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what FileOpenPicker API you are referring to? Please elaborate.

As far as the OneNote REST API is concerned, since audio files generated by OneNote are attachments, they can be fetched using the GET ~/Pages/{pageid}/content API followed by a subsequent authenticated GET ~/resource/{resource id of the audio attachment}/$value API.

Comment: I am referring to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx